# System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 & CPU time exceeded

Tags: apex, governorlimits, bestpractice

I am getting the following two errors in various scenarios of running an apex class
1) Too many SOQL queries
2) CPU time exceeded

The following is the **only method** in my controller class for extracting Organizations information as reports in a VF page. After going through best practices in apex i found that I shouldn't be using SOQL queries inside for loops. Is this the only problem because of which i am getting these errors. My controller has to iterate over **more than 50,000** records to generate these reports. How can I effectively do this without these errors.

```
public void fetchReports() {
    Integer cap = 0, comp = 0, sold = 0, issued = 0, available = 0, Ticket_count = 0;
    String percent;
    Decimal Value_sold = 0;
    outer_report = new List < OuterReportTable > ();
    pricetype_report = new List < PriceTypeReportTable > ();
    payment_report = new List < PaymentReportTable > ();
    CapacityTickets = new List < Ticket__c > ();

    Date fromDate = date.newinstance(fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c.year(), fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c.month(), fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c.day());
    Date toDate = date.newinstance(toDateEvent.Date_Time__c.year(), toDateEvent.Date_Time__c.month(), toDateEvent.Date_Time__c.day());


    //PriceTypeTable
    PriceType = [Select PriceType__r.Name from Ticket__c where Date_Time__c >= : fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Date_Time__c <= : toDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Activity__c = : activity.Activity__c];
    Map < String, Ticket__c > mapPriceType = new Map < String, Ticket__c > ();
    for (Ticket__c t_no: PriceType) {
        mapPriceType.put(String.valueOf(t_no.PriceType__r.Name), t_no); //map will always have unique values 
    }
    Unique_PriceType = new List < String > (mapPriceType.keySet());
    Integer sum_sold = 0;
    Decimal sum_value = 0.0;

    for (Integer j = 0; j < Unique_PriceType.size(); j++) {
        Price = [Select Price__c from Ticket__c where PriceType__r.Name = : Unique_PriceType.get(j) and Date_Time__c >= : fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Date_Time__c <= : toDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Activity__c = : activity.Activity__c];
        AggregateResult[] tickets_sold = [Select sum(Quantity__c) from Ticket__c where PriceType__r.Name = : Unique_PriceType.get(j) and Date_Time__c >= : fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Date_Time__c <= : toDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Activity__c = : activity.Activity__c];
        for (AggregateResult ar: tickets_sold) {
            Ticket_count = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'));
        }
        Decimal p = Ticket_count * Price.get(0).Price__c;
        sum_sold = sum_sold + Ticket_count;
        sum_value = sum_value + p;
        pricetype_report.add(new PriceTypeReportTable(Unique_PriceType.get(j), Price.get(0).Price__c, Ticket_count, p, Ticket_count, p));
    }
    pricetype_report.add(new PriceTypeReportTable('Total', null, sum_sold, sum_value, sum_sold, sum_value));

    //Payments Table
    String pay_type;
    Decimal Total_Payment, sum_payment = 0.0;
    AggregateResult[] Payment = [Select Type__c from Payment__c where Ticket__r.Date_Time__c >= : fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Ticket__r.Date_Time__c <= : toDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Ticket__r.Activity__c = : activity.Activity__c group by Type__c];
    for (AggregateResult ar1: Payment) {
        pay_type = String.valueOf(ar1.get('Type__c'));
        AggregateResult[] Total_Amount = [Select sum(Amount__c) from Payment__c where Type__c = : pay_type and Ticket__r.Date_Time__c >= : fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Ticket__r.Date_Time__c <= : toDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Ticket__r.Activity__c = : activity.Activity__c group by Type__c];
        for (AggregateResult ar2: Total_Amount) {
            Total_Payment = (Decimal)(ar2.get('expr0'));
            sum_payment = sum_payment + Total_Payment;
            payment_report.add(new PaymentReportTable(pay_type, Total_Payment));
            System.debug(pay_type);
            System.debug(Total_Amount);
        }
    }
    payment_report.add(new PaymentReportTable('Total', sum_payment));

}
```

Comment: oh oh so many query inside for loop.. try to avoid query inside for loop

Comment: While moving the queries out of the loops will solve the 101 queries problem, the CPU time exceeded problem may still exist if the loops are processing large volumes of data. You may have to resort to using asynchronous Apex (batchable) to generate the data into some kind of reporting table and present that. Or reduce the amount of data you consider per transaction.

Comment: How you name your variables is so confusing,  try and follow some convention.. It's really hard to read your code and you may get better answers if you fix it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through and querying for data each time you need data inside the loop, trying querying all the data you will need before your loop in to a list of data that you can reference.

Do this something like this instead:

```
Price__c[] prices = [Select Price__c from Ticket__c where PriceType__r.Name IN : Unique_PriceType and Date_Time__c >= : fromDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Date_Time__c <= : toDateEvent.Date_Time__c and Activity__c = : activity.Activity__c];

for (Integer j = 0; j < Unique_PriceType.size(); j++) {
    Price = prices[j];
    ...
```

Since you know you are going through so many records, you'll want to probably take the AggregateResults out as well, this would require a two dimensional array, but you can definitely remove that from the for-loop.

Everything else inside the for-loop can stay, you just have to change the references to your data like Price above.